# Entitydatasource to Datatable

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, entitydatasource

I have a Gridview that reads the DataSource from an EntityDataSrouce.
Now I want to convert the EntityDatasource of the gridview to DataTable so I can export it the Gridview as an Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to convert it to `DataTable` just to export. You can do it by gridview self.

Look at this link:
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html

In this article, the author uses a utility class that export it to .xls file, so, you can download it, add on your project and use like the sample.